# Largest chunk in a partition

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be the set of all ways of splitting a sequence of $m$ elements into $k$ non-empty chunks. (Of course, $|S| = \binom{m-1}{k-1}$.) Say $m=2k$, for instance. What would be an $L$ such that only a small proportion (= tending to $0$ for $m$ large) of elements of $S$ include a chunk of length $>L$?

(My feeling is that it is enough for $L/\log m$ to go to $\infty$, but I'd like to be sure.)

Comment: With $k=m$, all chunks are size 1 and $|S|=1$, of course. Perhaps you want a multiplier in there, $ak=m$?